# Какой из NavigationView был свёрнут?

Tags: java, android, android-sdk

Есть два `NavigationView` на одном экране.

Как в обработчике события `onDrawerClosed` определить какой из `NavigationView` был свёрнут?

Comment: У каждого вью есть идентификатор. Вот по этому идентификатору и определить.

Comment: @Эникейщик, `findViewById`  в данном случае не сработает. Но, за то работает `Tag`.

Comment: Так ``findViewByID`` в этом случае и не надо. Надо ``R.id.viewid``.

Comment: Уже пробовал. Не прокатило.

Answer (score 2):

Сам отвечаю на свой вопрос.

Нужно в `XML` присвоить `NavigationView` значение свойства `Tag`.

```
android:tag="same_tag"
```

После этого, можно легко определить, какой из `NavigationView` был свёрнут.

```
if ((view.getTag()!=null)&& view.getTag().equals("same_tag")) {
    int b = 50;
}
```

Нашёл [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3920833/android-imageview-getid-returning-integer).